# Eddy current in a coil

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a coil in a changing magnetic field. If the coil is part of a closed circuit, a current will flow. Is this eddy current? If not, then where is eddy current in this example?

Answer (score 1):

There is no eddy current in this example. If you have a conductor near this coil experiencing a time varying magnetic field, you will have eddy currents induced in the conductor.

Note added later. Eddy currents are induction currents in closed currents paths in (bulk) conductors. Their physical cause is the same as the induction in a wire loop: induced electric fields described by the Maxwell-Faraday equation $$\oint\limits_{\partial S} \mathbf{E} \cdot d\boldsymbol\ell = -\frac{d}{dt} \int\limits_S \mathbf{B} \cdot d\mathbf{a}$$ where $S$ is an arbitrarily chosen surface and  path $\partial{S}$ enclosing it. The electric field $\mathbf{E}$ together with the conductivity $\sigma$ produces a local current density $$\mathbf{j}=\sigma \mathbf{E}$$ In a coil consisting of a wire, you have, in principle, not only a current due to the EMF induced at the terminals of the coil (depending on the circuit termination) but also tiny local eddy current loops in the wire. These tiny eddy currents can usually be neglected. Therefore my statement above that there "is no eddy current" in this example. The induced current flowing over the terminals of a coil is usually not called an "eddy current".

Comment: So if this coil is in open cirsuit instead, then it will have eddy current?

Comment: @Amit Maurya - The current induced in a coil by a changing magnetic field is not called an "eddy current", it is an induced current. An eddy current is an (usually unwanted) current induced by a changing magnetic field in metal parts not related to circuits. If a coil is an open circuit, a voltage will be induced but no current can flow.

Comment: But you said "If you have a conductor near this coil experiencing a time varying magnetic field, you will have eddy currents induced in the conductor.". Doesn't the coil in open circuit qualify for eddy current?

Comment: @Amit Maurya - Eddy current are following the closed (circular) path of induced electric fields. Unless you have unusually thick coil wires you will have difficulties to produce eddy currents in an open coil with thin wires. In transformers, e.g., to prevent such closed current paths the transformer core is usually made of thin  isolated  magnetic metal sheets.

Comment: 1) Regarding transformer, does doing that eliminate eddies or reduces them because of increased resistance? 2) Whether eddy currents will be produced or not is function of thickness of conductor, even if magnetic field is changing?

Comment: @Amit Maurya - It eliminates the eddy currents because the induced electric fields causing them are vertical to the isolated sheets that block the currents. The changing magnetic fields produce electric fields in loops vertical to it. If in these loops you have a conductor, this will induce loop currents depending on the conductance of the conductor.

Comment: your argument still sounds flawed. See this picture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#/media/File:Laminated_core_eddy_currents_2.svg . Eddies are reduced not eliminated.

Comment: below what dimensions eddies will not be induced, for a given conductor?

Comment: @Amit Maurya - A conductor in a changing magnetic field has, in principle, always eddy currents. Also in small parts. However, by partitioning it into isolated sheets vertical to the currents, like in the core of a transformer, you can reduce them so much,  that the transformer core eddy currents are *practically* eliminated.

Comment: @Amit Maurya - You have even "eddy currents" in atoms, which one then calls diamagnetic.

Comment: so you are saying that there will be eddies in an open circuit coil, just in very small amount. now will there be eddies in a closed circuit coil lying in a changing magnetic field?

Comment: @Amit Maurya - In a changing magnetic field, there will be tiny local eddy currents in the wire of an open circuit coil and there will be tiny local eddy currents in the wire of a  closed circuit coil. See my note added to the original answer.

Comment: "The induced current flowing over the terminals of a coil is usually not called an "eddy current". " Not calling it "eddy" is a matter of norm. I am more interested in knowing if it is eddy current or not. If you can clarify it, that would be great.

Comment: @Amit Maurya - I made that clear in my note added to the answer.